# StatusCode Helper Method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a helper method for my ASP.NET Core 2.0 API method that will return a status code based on response I get from my back-end logic. I'm creating the helper method to eliminate repetitive code in multiple API methods.

I'm not sure what data type my helper method needs to return. Here's what I've got so far:

```
public static StatusCodes GetHttpStatus(string type)
{
   // I have some logic that I process here
   switch(type)
   {
       case "Success":
          return StatusCodes.Status200Ok;
       case "Unauthorized":
          return StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
   }
}
```

I want to call the helper method from my API method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    // Call my backend and get data
    var response = await _myServiceMethod.GetData();

    if(response.Type == "Success")
       return Ok(response.Data);

    return HelperMethods.GetHttpStatus(response.type);
}
```

What do I need to return from my `GetHttpStatus()` method? Is it `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes?view=aspnetcore-2.0) members are int values.

```
public const int Status200OK = 200;
```

So declare `int`.

```
public static int GetHttpStatus(string type)
{
    case "Success":
        return StatusCodes.Status200OK;
}
```

If your goal is to return directly from the Controller you might define a base controller instead.

```
public abstract class BaseApiController<T> : Controller where T : MyApiContent
{
    public virtual IActionResult ApiResult(string status, T content)
    {
        switch(status) 
        {
            case "Success":
                return Ok(content);
            case "Unauthorized":
                return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
}

public class MyApiContent
{
}

public class MyApiController : BaseApiController<MyApiContent>
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        MyApiContent content = await GetData();

        return ApiResult(content.type, content);
    }
}
```